# Simple NSURLRequest what am I missing?

Tags: ios, .net, nsurlconnection

```
  This works on my browser: http://121.242.90.79:6060/davitaservice.asmx?op=HelloWorld

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://121.242.90.79:6060/davitaservice.asmx/HelloWorld"];

  NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

  [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

  [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                           NSLog(@"repsonse %@",response);
                       }];
```

I get status code 500 any suggestions stack overflow community maybe I'm missing something simple

Comment: Entering the URL in the browser is a `GET`, not a `POST`.

Comment: Why are you adding the `Content-Type` header to the request? That's usually something sent back in the response.

Comment: `POST` request should identify `Content-Type` for type of the request body.

Answer (score 0):

what's the error message?

error 500 is internal server error, the request arrived to the server but it could not manage it

do you have access to the server? try reading his logs

PS: are you sure your server is waiting for a POST and not for a GET?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a post call, the parameter has to be passed as a parameter and not a part of your URL